# sqlite3_bind_text not binding the value

Tags: sqlite, prepared-statement

Please find the code . I could not find any errors . but the "Type1" supplied to ? in SQL is not binded via SQLITE3_BIND_TEXT.

I need your help, since im an amatuer programmer in sqlite.

```
 char * sql = "SELECT tube_id FROM tubes where type=?";
    sqlite3_stmt * stmt;
    sqlite3_prepare_v2 (db, sql, strlen (sql) + 1, & stmt, NULL);

    int rc=sqlite3_bind_text(stmt,1, /* The number of the argument. */ "Type1",-1,SQLITE_STATIC/* The callback. */);

    TRACE(_T("sql: %d %S\n "),rc, sql);
     int s = sqlite3_step (stmt);

     TRACE(_T("prepared query: %S\n"), sqlite3_sql(stmt));
     if (s == SQLITE_DONE) {
            int bytes;
            const unsigned char * text;
            bytes = sqlite3_column_bytes(stmt, 0);
            text  = sqlite3_column_text (stmt, 0);
           TRACE(_T("text: %S\n"), text);   
            TRACE(_T("stmt: %S\n"), bytes);   
        } else {
            fprintf (stderr, "Failed.\n");
     }
     sqlite3_reset(stmt);
     sqlite3_clear_bindings(stmt);
```

Comment: If `sqlite3_step` returns `SQLITE_DONE`, then that means there are no more rows to read, so calling `sqlite3_column_*` is invalid. `sqlite3_step` returns `SQLITE_ROW` if it fetched a row.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo Thank you! It helped me. After reading API, now  i have moved to easySQLite. Looks very easy.

Answer (score 0):

What @ColonelThirtyTwo told is correct. I have used SQLITE_ROW  to over come this problem.
Regards,
Selva